# Asking a user to input a number

Tags: java

so just want to make sure that my code's alright.

the objective is to displays a triangle 4 lines high, made up of two different numbers. The program will ask for two numbers: one between 0 and 4 and one between 5 and 9. The first and third line of the triangle will be filled with the first number; the second and last line of the triangle will be filled with the second number.

here's my code:

```js
/*This program displays a triangle 4 lines high, made up of two different
numbers. The program will ask for two numbers: one between 0 and 4 
and one between 5 and 9. The first and third line of the triangle 
will be filled with the first number; the second and last line of the
triangle will be filled with the second number. */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
      int num1, num2;
      
    System.out.print("Input a number between 0-4: ");
      num1 = keyboard.nextInt();
      
      System.out.print("Input a number between 5-9: ");
      num2 = keyboard.nextInt();
      
      if (num1>=0 && num1<=4 && num2>=5 && num2<=9){
      System.out.println("   \t   " + num1);
      System.out.println("  \t  "+num2 +" "+ num2);
      System.out.println(" \t " + num1+" "+ num1+" "+ num1);
      System.out.println("\t"+num2 +" "+ num2+" "+ num2+" "+ num2);

      }
      else{
         
      System.out.println("Please Try again!");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I can't tell what your question is... Is there something wrong with your code? Or a particular problem you're encountering? Does it not execute as you expected?
Edit: I tried it and it does exactly what you described... I fail to see any issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me.  I can't tell what your question is, but I did a few tests:

```
jakesyl@jakesyl-ubuntu:~$ javac Question.java 
jakesyl@jakesyl-ubuntu:~$ java Question 
Input a number between 0-4: 4
Input a number between 5-9: 8
       4
      8 8
     4 4 4
    8 8 8 8
jakesyl@jakesyl-ubuntu:~$ java Question 
Input a number between 0-4: 0
Input a number between 5-9: 2
Please Try again!
jakesyl@jakesyl-ubuntu:~$ java Question 
Input a number between 0-4: 4
Input a number between 5-9: 2
Please Try again!
jakesyl@jakesyl-ubuntu:~$ java Question 
Input a number between 0-4: 6
Input a number between 5-9: 9
Please Try again!
jakesyl@jakesyl-ubuntu:~$ java Question
Input a number between 0-4: 2
Input a number between 5-9: 4
Please Try again!
jakesyl@jakesyl-ubuntu:~$
```

Everything looks good here!